# Changing GenerationType.IDENTITY to GenerationType.SEQUENCE (and back) PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jpa, orm, key

We had database with entities using GenerationType.IDENTITY. There were some technical issues with it and I replaced it with GenerationType.SEQUENCE because I misunderstood what SEQUENCE does. Now we have database tables all numbered by +1 increments nicely until the point where usage of SEQUENCE started -> there the numbering is shared across all tables and quickly spirals to huge numbers with huge gaps in each table since it shared across the whole system.

When I reverted to IDENTITY now, it started numbering where it stopped when last used IDENTITY. Can (and what would happen if) IDENTITY provide number which would collide with number of SEQUENCE? (sadly I can not really test it because last IDENTITY entry is for example 9000 and first SEQUENCE is 25 mils - its because there is lot of addition/deletion in DB over month period)

Is there any way to maybe start numbering IDENTITY from the last SEQUENCE value then?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between IDENTITY and SEQUENCE  - a least in PostgreSQL - is that IDENTITY creates a sequence per table while SEQUENCE use one global sequence for all the tables as you noticed.

Assuming you have an entity named MyEntity (or my_entity as table name) - with IDENTITY strategy - there should be a sequence named something like: **my_entity_id_sequence**. SEQUENCE might be named (this depends on the JPA implementation) like **hibernate_sequence**.

If you can access the database - for example with [psql](/questions/tagged/psql) - you can just check the IDENTITY sequence and set its value:.

```
ALTER SEQUENCE my_entity_id_sequence RESTART with_your_value;
```

where **with_your_value** can be for example

```
SELECT max(id)+1 FROM my_entity;
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, chaging it to identity in code and then running this on DB for every class/table involved should make it numbered from the last value in that table thus protecting me from future collision, right?

Comment: @eXPRESS Yes if made correctly. When you changed to id type SEQUENCE JPA left the table IDENTITY sequence and started picking IDs from he global sequence. Then when switched back it started from where IDENTITY sequence was left. JPA picks the nextval('sequence_name') from used sequence atomically and postgres increases it in a not revertable way (so even rollback happens it does not revert sequence value back). Test it if not sure.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand you so if I will change it in code first, then run the app then do this in DB, then it is applied to the proper (identity) sequence and next value picked should be okay. Thank you very much.

Comment: @eXPRESS I think you better stop app make code changes & RESTART sequences then start app.

Comment: Okay, (I will test it anyway), but you are probably right.

Comment: I was testing it today and it seems that it should be just SELECT max(id) FROM my_entity without +1 since the bump will happen implicitly as new entry is inserted.

Comment: Ok. That was then just a safety margin that wasted one id.